# idea to write procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i  pass parameter as productid, i check in productrelated table whether this product 
related product are there or not if it is not there i want to check sample productid in departmentreplated  table if it is not there i find the department of the productid and find the that productid related  department product..

Plz help me how to write the store procedure.... 
 which logic i want to use....

help me writing procedure.... reply as soon as ...
thanks...

Comment: Proper spelling, punctuation, and putting some thought into the wording of your question go a long way.

Comment: Table schemas would go a long way to help, too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you really want an answer on this and tried your best to formulate the question.

The way you describe it you need to do that with a SELECT statement that does a LEFT JOIN. I cannot help you with the store procedure on SQL-SERVER but I guess you can figure out the rest once you have the SELECT.

```
SELECT ISNULL(p.someValue, d.someValue)
FROM DepartmentRelatedTable d
LEFT JOIN ProductRelatedTable p on (d.ProductId = p.ProductId)
WHERE d.ProductId = <some id here>
```

You maybe need to do a FULL JOIN instead of a LEFT JOIN because. I could not fully understand the data model you are using.